# code requirements for conduit attached to a bridge

Tags: electrical, wiring

I plan to run #2 aluminum MHF for a 300' run direct buried from the distribution panel to a sub panel. Part of the circuit will cross a small bridge across a creek. What does the code call for to cross the bridge? Schedule 40 1 1/2" conduit with hangers every 4 feet? The bridge length is 12 feet. Does the code require a transition to flex conduit on both sides of the bridge? Does liquid tight meet that standard? How do I transition from direct buried to flex and then to schedule 40 PVC? This work is in a flood plain. I followed a question string about trenching under a creek but don't want to risk involving ecology or other regulators other than electrical inspection (Labor and Industries in my state).

Comment: Depending on exposure (to damage) schedule 80 may be required rather than schedule 40 for PVC. Or, you may be able to run it in a position where the bridge structure protects it for most of the run. If not flex, then expansion fittings would make sense. Pretty sure hanger spacing is 10 feet or one per stick, plus a certain much shorter distance from any junction or pull boxes that might add a couple.

Comment: @Ecnerwal table 352.30(B) PVC support spacing minimum is 5'

Comment: Right, I'm more familiar with the EMT rule as that's the bulk of my conduit.

Comment: Running the whole thinh in conduit or just sleeving at exposed locations?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Reads as MHF direct burial with sleeving only at the bridge to me...

Comment: OP, are you thinking to attach the conduit to the side, or the bottom of the bridge?

Comment: Huesmann, I'll be attaching to the underside of wood planking on the bridge. I can run between the 2 I beams if protection is a concern.